# Jetpack Compose AlertDialog content layout size

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-jetpack-compose

I created the dialog using Jetpack Compose. However, I set the size of the dialog item to 300dp and align it to the center, but my items are clipped and it doesn't work. I think this bug occurs because the size of the column, which is the layout of the item, cannot be specified. How can I solve this?

This is my dialog source:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun ExceptionDialog(visible: MutableState<Boolean>, exception: Exception) {
    if (visible.value) {
        val context = LocalContext.current
        val contents = listOf("눈덩이", "돌덩이", "나뭇가지", "새똥", "나뭇잎", "흙더미")
        val composition by rememberLottieComposition(LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.something_error))

        AlertDialog(
            modifier = Modifier.size(350.dp),
            onDismissRequest = { visible.value = false },
            properties = DialogProperties(usePlatformDefaultWidth = false),
            confirmButton = {
                exception.message?.let { exceptionMessage ->
                    OutlinedButton(onClick = { Util.copy(context, exceptionMessage) }) {
                        Text(text = "에러 복사")
                    }
                }
            },
            text = {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier.size(300.dp),
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                ) {
                    LottieAnimation(
                        modifier = Modifier.size(200.dp),
                        iterations = LottieConstants.IterateForever,
                        composition = composition,
                    )
                    Text(
                        text = "깃메봇이가 예상치 못한 ${contents.random()}에 맞았어요 \uD83E\uDD72\n${exception.message}",
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        color = Color.Black
                    )
                }
            },
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(30.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

This is result screen:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand. What's clipped here? Seems all fine to me;

Comment: I'm sorry that the information delivery is not clear. I just wanted to say that `LottieAnimation` composable got clipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `AlertDialog` aligns the view when it finds the first `Text` inside the `text` block, so your view shifts.

I'm not sure if this is a bug, or if it's just not meant to be used that way.

The good news is that you can put your animated view inside `title`. This will work the same way as `text`, meaning you can only have a custom view **or** `Text` inside both `title` and `text`.

```
@Composable
fun ExceptionDialog(visible: MutableState<Boolean>, exception: Exception) {
    if (visible.value) {
        val contents = listOf("눈덩이", "돌덩이", "나뭇가지", "새똥", "나뭇잎", "흙더미")
        val composition by rememberLottieComposition(LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.something_error))

        AlertDialog(
            onDismissRequest = { visible.value = false },
            properties = DialogProperties(usePlatformDefaultWidth = false),
            confirmButton = {
                exception.message?.let { exceptionMessage ->
                    OutlinedButton(onClick = { }) {
                        Text(text = "에러 복사")
                    }
                }
            },
            title = {
                Box(
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                ) {
                    LottieAnimation(
                        iterations = LottieConstants.IterateForever,
                        composition = composition,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(200.dp)
                    )
                }
            },
            text = {
                Text(
                    text = "깃메봇이가 예상치 못한 ${contents.random()}에 맞았어요 \uD83E\uDD72\n${exception.message}",
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    color = Color.Black,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                )
            },
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(30.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

[image]